# Generating a number while encrypting a string

Tags: scala, encryption

I am not an expert in Encryption but I have a requirement to generate a number from the input string and convert it back to the original string.

I have searched a lot on the internet but could not find anyone doing this. Therefore, I would like to take help from the experts on StackOverflow.

As far as I am aware of encryption of a string to number is a bit tricky but the project in which I am working demands this.

Any libraries which do this or any algorithms will solve my problem.

Here is the code I have so far

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.util
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64


    object DataMaskUtil {

        def encrypt(key: String, value: String): String = {
          val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyToSpec(key))
           Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8")))
        }

        def decrypt(key: String, encryptedValue: String): String = {
          val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING")
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyToSpec(key))
          new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedValue)))
        }

        def keyToSpec(key: String): SecretKeySpec = {
          var keyBytes: Array[Byte] = (SALT + key).getBytes("UTF-8")
          val sha: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
          keyBytes = sha.digest(keyBytes)
          keyBytes = util.Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, 16)
          new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES")
        }

         private val SALT: String =
        "jMhKlOuJnM34G6NHkqo9V010GhLAqOpF0BePojHgh1HgNg8^72k"

    }
```

Using the idea provided by Maarten Bodewes

```
object Util2 {

  def encrypt(value: String): BigInteger = {
    val ct = value.getBytes()
    val abyte = 0x4D.toByte
    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2+ct.length)
    byteBuffer.put(abyte).put(abyte)
    byteBuffer.put(ct)
    val number = new BigInteger(byteBuffer.array())
    number
  }

  def decrypt(ctAsNumber: BigInteger): String = {
    if (ctAsNumber.signum < 0 || ctAsNumber.bitLength < 15) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Magic of ciphertext number doesn't match")
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer
    val fixed = ByteBuffer.allocate((ctAsNumber.bitLength + java.lang.Byte.SIZE - 1) / java.lang.Byte.SIZE)
    fixed.put(ctAsNumber.toByteArray)
    fixed.flip()
    val ct = new Array[Byte](fixed.remaining())
    fixed.get(ct)
    new String(ct)
  }
}
```

When i test the functions the output is padded with "MM" before the string

```
object MainClass {

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
        val encrypt = Util2.encrypt("Hi")
        println("The encrypted string is :: "+encrypt)

        val decrypt = Util2.decrypt(encrypt)
        println("The decrypted string is :: "+decrypt)

      }

    }
```

output

```
The encrypted string is :: 1296910441
The decrypted string is :: MMHi
```

Comment: Your `encrypt` method is supposed to return an integer while your `decrypt` method expects a string representing the encrypted data, after you encrypt some data, you'll get back an array of bytes which you can base 64 encode, for decrypting it, you base 64 decode and the, try to decrypt the bytes.

Comment: thanks i corrected that. I copied the code while trying to get Integer.

Comment: Your code still tries to parse the encryped string into an integer, please post what results are you getting once it is changed.

Comment: You should use a Password Based KDF such as PBKDF2 to create a key from a password. Keys are binary, so your `keyToSpec` may be insecure. ECB mode is dangerous as well of course and may expand the ciphertext more due to the PKCS#5/7 compatible padding. Don't stringify your code, use the types as they are intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are of course multiple ways of doing this. But lets assume that we want positive values (usually required by cryptography) and that we want the result to work for ECB and CBC but also for e.g. CTR mode encryption. In that case we also need to make sure that leading zero's are handled gracefully, because leading zero's do have significance in ciphertext, but not for numbers.

And, this being a language running on the JVM, we'll use big endian as well.

Negative values and zero bytes can be easily avoided by adding bit / byte values to the left hand side. We could for instance use well known values, which let you have some kind of minimal protection against mangling of the ciphertext number as well. Then you would get, in Java:

```
private static BigInteger ciphertextToNumber(byte[] ct) {
    ByteBuffer fixed = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 + ct.length);
    fixed.put((byte) 0x4D).put((byte) 0x42);
    fixed.put(ct);
    BigInteger number = new BigInteger(fixed.array());
    return number;
}

private static byte[] numberToCiphertext(BigInteger ctAsNumber) {
    // if the number is negative then the buffer will be too small
    if (ctAsNumber.signum() < 0 || ctAsNumber.bitLength() < 15) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Magic of ciphertext number doesn't match");
    }
    ByteBuffer fixed = ByteBuffer.allocate((ctAsNumber.bitLength() + Byte.SIZE - 1) / Byte.SIZE);
    fixed.put(ctAsNumber.toByteArray());
    fixed.flip();
    if (fixed.get() != (byte) 0x4D || fixed.get() != (byte) 0x42) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Magic of ciphertext number doesn't match");
    }
    byte[] ct = new byte[fixed.remaining()];
    fixed.get(ct);
    return ct;
}
```

This is relatively performant and it doesn't grow the possible number too much compared to the ciphertext (as the ciphertext can have any byte value, it is of course not possible to compress it instead). One optimization would be to extract the byte values of the magic directly from the `BigInteger`, but one additional copy of the ciphertext probably doesn't hurt much for this kind of purpose.

I'll leave it to you to convert to Scala.

---

Another idea is to use I2OSP or OS2IP as defined in the RSA RFC's, but note that RSA padding already performs the same kind of left-padding to make sure that the byte array to integer conversion is handled gracefully. Furthermore, the RSA ciphertext is always the same size as the modulus, while AES encryption may return different sizes.

Comment: I have tried your code to convert cipher text to number and number to cipher text. But i am getting BufferUnderflowException. Could you please help me.

Comment: Sure, but not without the exact code and stack trace. Maybe you could (temporarily) add it to your question? I was in my kayak, a good excuse to go offline for a while :)

Comment: I added my code and stack trace to the question in the end

Comment: `oos.writeObject(fixed.remaining())` ... `remaining` returns an integer.  The string handling that comes afterward is completely unnecessary and wrong. Why not try and create the exact methods in Scala and test them separately first? You don't need the streams and such. Heh, now you have MM as magic instead of MB - that was just a joke, you can use a single byte (in the range `01` to `7F`) :P

Comment: FInally, I could make the code work. But the when i get the string back it is appended by "MM" in the starting. COuld you please guide me how to fix this. I have added the latest code.

Comment: @wandermonk; You put `0x4D` in (twice) but forgot to take them out after the `flip()`.

Comment: Yep, correct. BTW, for some reason I don't seem to always get pinged when a comment is added here. Or maybe I'm just not noticing.

Comment: One last question: When i am using the AES encryption and using the above logic the output string is very large in the range of 108 character length. Is there a way i can reduce the length. Example output string i got is "709172944675511518327197725955407111690251495577504559081063754834542250674191145802769453014867007680104777"

Comment: No. Well, as I mentioned you can replace the MB and instead use a byte set to the value one (1). That simply expands the ciphertext with one bit. This is obviously the best you can do because ciphertext can, by definition, not be compressed.